# Deploying muli-container web-app on Azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a multi-container webapp on the Azure Cloud Services but impossible to run the application. I have no idea where the problem comes from.

My project consists of two Docker images: one dedicated to the application (my_app) and one dedicated the a PostgreSQL DB (my_db). Here are the Docker files corresponding to the creation of these images:

Dockerfile of my_app:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y python3-psycopg2
RUN pip3 install streamlit && pip3 install cython
RUN pip3 install openpyxl
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8501
COPY ./ /streamlit-docker/
WORKDIR /streamlit-docker/
CMD export STREAMLIT_SERVER_PORT=$PORT ; streamlit run main_app.py
```

Dockerfile of my_db:

```
FROM postgres:latest
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password
ENV POSTGRES_DB=my_db
ENV POSTGRES_USER=my_user
EXPOSE 5432
COPY db_rh.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2.0"

services:
        db:
                image: my_cr.azurecr.io/my_db

        app:
                image: my_cr.azurecr.io/my_app
                ports:
                        - '80:8501'
                depends_on:
                        - db
```

This application works well in local with these images. Then, for deploying this application on Azure, I followed these steps:

- Creation of a resource group
- Creation of a container registry with the images my_app and my_db
- Creation of an app service plan
- Creation of a web app with the following configuration: Docker container (Publish), Linux (OS), Azure Container Registry (Image Source), Docker compose (options), Azure Container Registry (image source), docker-compose.yml (configuration file)

The creation of this app service works fine but when trying to access the application via the URL, I get the following Server error:

"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server."

Here is the full content of my container logs:

```
2021-08-05T07:54:34.720Z INFO  - Starting multi-container app..
2021-08-05T07:54:35.179Z INFO  - Pulling image: my_cr.azurecr.io/my_db
2021-08-05T07:54:35.498Z INFO  - latest Pulling from my_db
2021-08-05T07:54:35.499Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:74d3869cb2f42dca24421efb98b7509069920bbbd0f2f865a5e64ba30557961f
2021-08-05T07:54:35.499Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for my_cr.azurecr.io/my_db:latest
2021-08-05T07:54:35.501Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2021-08-05T07:54:35.512Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-08-05T07:54:35.512Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 6022:5432 --name my_app_db_0_08f8304d -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my_app -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my_app.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=64bc73e3a7abb411766354d386a7f0c2b2478449abedacd9a87a34854de7a75a my_cr.azurecr.io/my_db  

2021-08-05T07:54:35.512Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-08-05T07:54:35.991Z INFO  - Pulling image: my_cr.azurecr.io/my_app
2021-08-05T07:54:36.264Z INFO  - latest Pulling from my_app
2021-08-05T07:54:36.264Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:cd06507e2d55f131d2dd04a56647617b22aeb26d23a3b1001bda39fa6c2027ec
2021-08-05T07:54:36.264Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for my_cr.azurecr.io/my_app:latest
2021-08-05T07:54:36.266Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2021-08-05T07:54:36.273Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2021-08-05T07:54:36.273Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 0:8501 --name my_app_app_0_08f8304d -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=my_app -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=my_app.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=64bc73e3a7abb411766354d386a7f0c2b2478449abedacd9a87a34854de7a75a my_cr.azurecr.io/my_app  

2021-08-05T07:54:36.273Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2021-08-05T07:58:27.330Z ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully
2021-08-05T07:58:27.356Z INFO  - Container logs from my_app_db_0_08f8304d = 2021-08-05T07:54:39.624400605Z The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2021-08-05T07:54:39.625150532Z This user must also own the server process.
2021-08-05T07:54:39.625163232Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:39.626103466Z The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2021-08-05T07:54:39.626877394Z The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2021-08-05T07:54:39.626889795Z The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2021-08-05T07:54:39.626894195Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:39.626897695Z Data page checksums are disabled.
2021-08-05T07:54:39.626901295Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:39.628892567Z fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2021-08-05T07:54:39.628906968Z creating subdirectories ... ok
2021-08-05T07:54:39.629589593Z selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2021-08-05T07:54:39.656824379Z selecting default max_connections ... 100
2021-08-05T07:54:39.687252281Z selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2021-08-05T07:54:39.740016291Z selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2021-08-05T07:54:39.741740954Z creating configuration files ... ok
2021-08-05T07:54:40.068593789Z running bootstrap script ... ok
2021-08-05T07:54:41.004087061Z performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2021-08-05T07:54:42.230641572Z syncing data to disk ... ok
2021-08-05T07:54:42.231317196Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:42.231897217Z initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232095325Z You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232116725Z --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232300832Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232334933Z Success. You can now start the database server using:
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232340533Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232343934Z     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2021-08-05T07:54:42.232347534Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:42.456194139Z waiting for server to start....2021-08-05 07:54:42.456 UTC [44] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-08-05T07:54:42.496248289Z 2021-08-05 07:54:42.496 UTC [44] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-08-05T07:54:42.654349413Z 2021-08-05 07:54:42.654 UTC [45] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 07:54:40 UTC
2021-08-05T07:54:42.746823961Z 2021-08-05 07:54:42.746 UTC [44] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05T07:54:42.783035373Z  done
2021-08-05T07:54:42.783885303Z server started
2021-08-05T07:54:44.054632713Z CREATE DATABASE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.056384276Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:44.056973898Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:44.057666823Z /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_rh.sql
2021-08-05T07:54:44.221355749Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.222769601Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.223381423Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.224206353Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.225258591Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.227164960Z  set_config 
2021-08-05T07:54:44.227179460Z ------------
2021-08-05T07:54:44.227184260Z  
2021-08-05T07:54:44.227187861Z (1 row)
2021-08-05T07:54:44.227191561Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:44.228905423Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.229617648Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.230499680Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.230512781Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.230971197Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.232521654Z SET
2021-08-05T07:54:44.277558484Z CREATE TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.315623762Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.335845295Z CREATE TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.356854955Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.377606507Z CREATE TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.398614267Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.438168299Z CREATE TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.457002081Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.477301216Z CREATE TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.498951400Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.499750529Z COPY 0
2021-08-05T07:54:44.500445354Z COPY 0
2021-08-05T07:54:44.502041812Z COPY 0
2021-08-05T07:54:44.502772838Z COPY 0
2021-08-05T07:54:44.503399861Z COPY 0
2021-08-05T07:54:44.600390873Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.679034324Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.760520588Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.820774680Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.882028508Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:44.962060520Z CREATE INDEX
2021-08-05T07:54:44.982679670Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:45.003139914Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:45.022835530Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:45.042545347Z ALTER TABLE
2021-08-05T07:54:45.043895697Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:45.044546920Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:45.054186771Z waiting for server to shut down...2021-08-05 07:54:45.054 UTC [44] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-08-05T07:54:45.104737810Z .2021-08-05 07:54:45.104 UTC [44] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-08-05T07:54:45.113094314Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.113 UTC [44] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 51) exited with exit code 1
2021-08-05T07:54:45.115152089Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.115 UTC [46] LOG:  shutting down
2021-08-05T07:54:45.555569909Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.554 UTC [44] LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-08-05T07:54:45.559094037Z  done
2021-08-05T07:54:45.559820164Z server stopped
2021-08-05T07:54:45.560410685Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:45.560950305Z PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
2021-08-05T07:54:45.560963205Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:45.684720007Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.684 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-08-05T07:54:45.691463352Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.691 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-08-05T07:54:45.701926133Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.692 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-08-05T07:54:45.797674616Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.797 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-08-05T07:54:45.894399334Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.894 UTC [81] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 07:54:45 UTC
2021-08-05T07:54:45.908581650Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.908 UTC [82] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:45.960868752Z 2021-08-05 07:54:45.960 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05T07:54:46.923208257Z 2021-08-05 07:54:46.922 UTC [89] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:47.935920894Z 2021-08-05 07:54:47.935 UTC [90] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:48.956866030Z 2021-08-05 07:54:48.956 UTC [91] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:49.971780246Z 2021-08-05 07:54:49.971 UTC [92] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:50.981966990Z 2021-08-05 07:54:50.981 UTC [94] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:51.990014754Z 2021-08-05 07:54:51.989 UTC [95] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:52.998793493Z 2021-08-05 07:54:52.998 UTC [96] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:54.009655500Z 2021-08-05 07:54:54.009 UTC [97] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:55.017764808Z 2021-08-05 07:54:55.017 UTC [98] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:56.027214763Z 2021-08-05 07:54:56.027 UTC [99] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:57.039281012Z 2021-08-05 07:54:57.036 UTC [100] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:58.053551741Z 2021-08-05 07:54:58.053 UTC [101] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:54:59.062191265Z 2021-08-05 07:54:59.062 UTC [102] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:00.073771695Z 2021-08-05 07:55:00.073 UTC [103] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:01.082230724Z 2021-08-05 07:55:01.082 UTC [104] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:02.092564548Z 2021-08-05 07:55:02.092 UTC [105] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:03.104064712Z 2021-08-05 07:55:03.103 UTC [106] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:04.112175958Z 2021-08-05 07:55:04.111 UTC [107] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:05.120723018Z 2021-08-05 07:55:05.120 UTC [108] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:06.128742159Z 2021-08-05 07:55:06.128 UTC [109] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:07.137263517Z 2021-08-05 07:55:07.137 UTC [110] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:08.148442867Z 2021-08-05 07:55:08.148 UTC [111] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:09.169346810Z 2021-08-05 07:55:09.161 UTC [112] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:10.172877800Z 2021-08-05 07:55:10.172 UTC [113] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:11.181602066Z 2021-08-05 07:55:11.181 UTC [114] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:12.189966019Z 2021-08-05 07:55:12.189 UTC [115] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:13.200831156Z 2021-08-05 07:55:13.200 UTC [116] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:14.209124505Z 2021-08-05 07:55:14.208 UTC [117] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:15.218337785Z 2021-08-05 07:55:15.218 UTC [118] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:16.226075387Z 2021-08-05 07:55:16.225 UTC [120] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:17.234564848Z 2021-08-05 07:55:17.234 UTC [121] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:18.245693074Z 2021-08-05 07:55:18.245 UTC [122] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:19.255450228Z 2021-08-05 07:55:19.255 UTC [123] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:20.270511372Z 2021-08-05 07:55:20.264 UTC [124] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:21.273793492Z 2021-08-05 07:55:21.273 UTC [125] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:22.282482606Z 2021-08-05 07:55:22.282 UTC [126] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:23.292355263Z 2021-08-05 07:55:23.292 UTC [127] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:24.301818803Z 2021-08-05 07:55:24.301 UTC [128] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:25.310154158Z 2021-08-05 07:55:25.310 UTC [129] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:26.321577717Z 2021-08-05 07:55:26.321 UTC [130] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:27.338986845Z 2021-08-05 07:55:27.331 UTC [131] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:28.369406547Z 2021-08-05 07:55:28.361 UTC [132] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:29.375026698Z 2021-08-05 07:55:29.374 UTC [133] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:30.385248609Z 2021-08-05 07:55:30.384 UTC [134] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:31.402910678Z 2021-08-05 07:55:31.402 UTC [135] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:32.419738718Z 2021-08-05 07:55:32.419 UTC [136] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:33.441062540Z 2021-08-05 07:55:33.437 UTC [137] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:34.463932369Z 2021-08-05 07:55:34.463 UTC [138] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:35.477585383Z 2021-08-05 07:55:35.477 UTC [139] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:36.486166422Z 2021-08-05 07:55:36.486 UTC [140] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:37.494644457Z 2021-08-05 07:55:37.494 UTC [141] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:38.509526210Z 2021-08-05 07:55:38.509 UTC [142] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:39.521249455Z 2021-08-05 07:55:39.520 UTC [143] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:40.531927864Z 2021-08-05 07:55:40.528 UTC [144] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:41.537468399Z 2021-08-05 07:55:41.537 UTC [145] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:42.546186210Z 2021-08-05 07:55:42.546 UTC [146] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:43.555275734Z 2021-08-05 07:55:43.555 UTC [147] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:44.562742499Z 2021-08-05 07:55:44.562 UTC [148] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:45.571263301Z 2021-08-05 07:55:45.571 UTC [149] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:46.580387325Z 2021-08-05 07:55:46.580 UTC [151] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:47.589074832Z 2021-08-05 07:55:47.588 UTC [152] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:48.603082433Z 2021-08-05 07:55:48.597 UTC [153] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:49.607446299Z 2021-08-05 07:55:49.607 UTC [154] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:50.619281079Z 2021-08-05 07:55:50.615 UTC [155] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:51.625251846Z 2021-08-05 07:55:51.623 UTC [156] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:52.632862471Z 2021-08-05 07:55:52.632 UTC [157] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:53.641866947Z 2021-08-05 07:55:53.641 UTC [158] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:54.653580021Z 2021-08-05 07:55:54.653 UTC [159] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:55.661719164Z 2021-08-05 07:55:55.661 UTC [160] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:56.669939482Z 2021-08-05 07:55:56.669 UTC [161] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:57.678812352Z 2021-08-05 07:55:57.678 UTC [162] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:58.687793838Z 2021-08-05 07:55:58.687 UTC [163] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:55:59.699769122Z 2021-08-05 07:55:59.699 UTC [164] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:00.716650167Z 2021-08-05 07:56:00.716 UTC [165] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:01.725577950Z 2021-08-05 07:56:01.725 UTC [166] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:02.747925473Z 2021-08-05 07:56:02.747 UTC [167] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:03.759682548Z 2021-08-05 07:56:03.759 UTC [168] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:04.771765433Z 2021-08-05 07:56:04.771 UTC [169] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:05.784807652Z 2021-08-05 07:56:05.784 UTC [170] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:06.803539504Z 2021-08-05 07:56:06.794 UTC [171] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:07.807353350Z 2021-08-05 07:56:07.807 UTC [172] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:08.817336104Z 2021-08-05 07:56:08.817 UTC [173] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:09.824894676Z 2021-08-05 07:56:09.824 UTC [174] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:10.833040967Z 2021-08-05 07:56:10.832 UTC [175] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:11.842120489Z 2021-08-05 07:56:11.841 UTC [176] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:12.855950672Z 2021-08-05 07:56:12.850 UTC [177] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:13.860347575Z 2021-08-05 07:56:13.860 UTC [178] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:14.868976169Z 2021-08-05 07:56:14.868 UTC [179] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:15.877357555Z 2021-08-05 07:56:15.877 UTC [180] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:16.885764041Z 2021-08-05 07:56:16.885 UTC [182] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:17.894124324Z 2021-08-05 07:56:17.893 UTC [183] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:18.909025945Z 2021-08-05 07:56:18.908 UTC [184] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:19.916682502Z 2021-08-05 07:56:19.916 UTC [185] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:20.925094086Z 2021-08-05 07:56:20.924 UTC [186] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:21.933015990Z 2021-08-05 07:56:21.932 UTC [187] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:22.940664917Z 2021-08-05 07:56:22.940 UTC [188] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:23.952057472Z 2021-08-05 07:56:23.951 UTC [189] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:24.962597097Z 2021-08-05 07:56:24.962 UTC [190] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:25.971645871Z 2021-08-05 07:56:25.971 UTC [191] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:26.981238163Z 2021-08-05 07:56:26.980 UTC [192] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:27.993425043Z 2021-08-05 07:56:27.993 UTC [193] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:29.002914331Z 2021-08-05 07:56:29.002 UTC [194] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:30.011207268Z 2021-08-05 07:56:30.010 UTC [195] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:31.025278976Z 2021-08-05 07:56:31.018 UTC [196] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:32.216948573Z 2021-08-05 07:56:32.216 UTC [197] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:33.228487181Z 2021-08-05 07:56:33.228 UTC [198] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:34.237630694Z 2021-08-05 07:56:34.237 UTC [199] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:35.252393227Z 2021-08-05 07:56:35.252 UTC [200] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:36.266005461Z 2021-08-05 07:56:36.265 UTC [201] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:37.274159443Z 2021-08-05 07:56:37.274 UTC [202] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:38.282400220Z 2021-08-05 07:56:38.282 UTC [203] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:39.290373288Z 2021-08-05 07:56:39.290 UTC [204] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:40.299752804Z 2021-08-05 07:56:40.299 UTC [205] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:41.308719006Z 2021-08-05 07:56:41.308 UTC [206] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:42.317175889Z 2021-08-05 07:56:42.316 UTC [207] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:43.326289595Z 2021-08-05 07:56:43.326 UTC [208] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:44.340279974Z 2021-08-05 07:56:44.340 UTC [209] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:45.353474420Z 2021-08-05 07:56:45.353 UTC [210] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:46.362194374Z 2021-08-05 07:56:46.361 UTC [212] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:47.371297641Z 2021-08-05 07:56:47.371 UTC [213] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:48.380459110Z 2021-08-05 07:56:48.380 UTC [214] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:49.389660180Z 2021-08-05 07:56:49.389 UTC [215] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:50.411080182Z 2021-08-05 07:56:50.400 UTC [216] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:51.413900925Z 2021-08-05 07:56:51.413 UTC [217] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:52.421513037Z 2021-08-05 07:56:52.421 UTC [218] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:53.429621963Z 2021-08-05 07:56:53.429 UTC [219] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:54.440013566Z 2021-08-05 07:56:54.439 UTC [220] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:55.447874578Z 2021-08-05 07:56:55.447 UTC [221] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:56.465305134Z 2021-08-05 07:56:56.455 UTC [222] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:57.475737737Z 2021-08-05 07:56:57.471 UTC [223] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:58.485066601Z 2021-08-05 07:56:58.484 UTC [224] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:56:59.507571938Z 2021-08-05 07:56:59.507 UTC [225] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:00.516233176Z 2021-08-05 07:57:00.515 UTC [226] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:01.524555070Z 2021-08-05 07:57:01.524 UTC [227] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:02.536118582Z 2021-08-05 07:57:02.532 UTC [228] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:03.540761345Z 2021-08-05 07:57:03.540 UTC [229] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:04.550800001Z 2021-08-05 07:57:04.550 UTC [230] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:05.559268400Z 2021-08-05 07:57:05.559 UTC [231] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:06.567084876Z 2021-08-05 07:57:06.566 UTC [232] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:07.576160396Z 2021-08-05 07:57:07.576 UTC [233] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:08.587247688Z 2021-08-05 07:57:08.587 UTC [234] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:09.604397733Z 2021-08-05 07:57:09.604 UTC [235] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:10.614805949Z 2021-08-05 07:57:10.614 UTC [236] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:11.624866650Z 2021-08-05 07:57:11.624 UTC [237] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:12.635468272Z 2021-08-05 07:57:12.635 UTC [238] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:13.644411631Z 2021-08-05 07:57:13.644 UTC [239] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:14.662676945Z 2021-08-05 07:57:14.654 UTC [240] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:15.671643703Z 2021-08-05 07:57:15.671 UTC [241] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:16.680187744Z 2021-08-05 07:57:16.679 UTC [243] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:17.688120645Z 2021-08-05 07:57:17.687 UTC [244] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:18.696144687Z 2021-08-05 07:57:18.696 UTC [245] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:19.705499276Z 2021-08-05 07:57:19.705 UTC [246] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:57:20.719966148Z 2021-08-05 07:57:20.715 UTC [247] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
...
2021-08-05T07:58:25.317360209Z 2021-08-05 07:58:25.317 UTC [313] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-08-05T07:58:26.325240470Z 2021-08-05 07:58:26.324 UTC [314] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet

2021-08-05T07:58:29.497Z INFO  - Container logs from my_app_app_0_08f8304d = 2021-08-05T07:54:46.838562178Z 2021-08-05 07:54:46.838 INFO    matplotlib.font_manager: generated new fontManager
2021-08-05T07:54:47.814484977Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:47.825676884Z   You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.
2021-08-05T07:54:47.826413011Z 
2021-08-05T07:54:47.827449249Z   Network URL: http://172.16.69.3:8501
2021-08-05T07:54:47.827983168Z   External URL: http://20.74.4.82:8501
2021-08-05T07:54:47.828572390Z 

2021-08-05T07:58:32.246Z INFO  - Stopping site my_app because it failed during startup.
```

I have been searching for hours and trying to change the configuration multiple times but nothing made it work.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Best,

Clank

Comment: If you view the webapp on the Azure portal and select Container settings (Classic) on the left hand Settings menu, you'll be able to view the container logs from the logs tab. Can you see anything in the logs?
Are you doing your deployment steps via the Azure portal or using the Azure CLI?

Comment: I have tried the deployment both via the Azure portal and the Azure CLI but the same error happened all the time.

Concerning the logs, I have found the following issues 'Invalid length of startup packet' which seems to come from the db image but I don't think it explains the fact that the app doesn't show up because even with a defective DB my app should show up... At the end of the logs I also have the following: 'Stopping site my_webapp because it failed during startup'

Comment: Try exposing an explicit port in your my_app dockerfile? (i.e. `8501`) and set it as the `STREAMLIT_SERVER_PORT` variable too?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the content of the container logs into your questions please

Comment: Hello, I tried this all but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: You mention below you're now getting Application Error rather than server error, can you copy and paste your latest container logs either into the question or as a comment final 20 lines should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Build sections from your Compose file as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux) states that the Build command is not supported.  Your containers are already built and deployed in ACR so this is not needed.

> Unsupported options
>
> - build (not allowed)
> - depends_on (ignored)
> - networks (ignored)
> - secrets (ignored)
> - ports other than 80 and 8080 (ignored)

You're exposing your app on port 8501.  Make sure to create an application setting to map that port using the Portal or the CLI.

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8501
```

You can also edit your Compose file to map port 80 to 8501

```
ports:
  - '80:8501'
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your help. I have already tried these two ways but nothing helps... Instead of getting a server error I get  ':( Application Error'.

Comment: Well, you're getting further.  You know that your containers are starting but the app fails.  Have you enabled app logging like stated in the container logs you added to your question?

Comment: Hello,
I am not sure I understand what is meant by enabling app logging. I have simply gone on the Azure app service to: Monitoring -> App Service logs -> Application logging : File System. What else should I do?

Comment: This will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/capture-application-logs-app-service/

Comment: Couldn't find anything helpful there neither... :/